# changing image from other class

Tags: android

I have main activity class and main layout. I have other class named time. I want to change set the icon on the main layout from other class. How can I do that ?

```
public class Time extends TimerTask
public class Main extends Activity
```

Time class is running on each 3 seconds. In run method, I have tried

```
    ImageView image;
@Override
public void run() {
              image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
              image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);
    }
```

But, gives error. "findViewById" is not implemented in this class.

EDIT :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/isViolate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:src="@drawable/set2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
image = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Did you try using this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Comment: Insteresting thing is that R.id.imageView1 is not exist. Why, I do not understand

Comment: Now, it sees the imageView1 but for `getView`, it gives `The method getView() is undefined for the type Time` . I have go into the lint error and then made it restore defaults.

Comment: Check if you have any errors in the project. Try to clean the project and try again

Comment: There is no error on the project. What is the meaning of the error ?

Comment: Error here mean which doesn't allow you to compile the code. the change in xml file might not be reflected.